# Scheme (DrRacket) syntax - parentheses

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket, parentheses

Let's take a look at the following functions:

```
(define Increment1 (λ(x)(+ x 1)))
(define (Increment2)
    (define (inc2 x)(+ x 1))
    inc2)
```

They both return functions which increments x.

Question 1:
Given the code:

```
(define Func Increment2)
(Func 2)
```

Why do I get an error? (Expected number of arguments = 0, given = 1),
While the code

```
(define Func2 (Increment2))
(Func2 2)
```

will work and will return a 3. Why is that?

Question 2: Why when defining a function with a lambda, we do not need to wrap it with parentheses? (case Increment1)
On the other hand, why do we wrap a function name with parentheses when not using a lambda? (case Increment2)

Question 3: Let's define a function `(define Func3 (λ(F x)(F x)))`.

Why would `(Func3 Increment1 2)` will work but `(Func3 Increment2 2)` will fail? (same error as in Question 1).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Increment2` is a function whose return value is a function. Therefore, you need to call `Increment2` to get its return value, which is a function.

Looking at your second listing:

```
(define Func2 (Increment2))
(Func2 2)
```

We notice that `Func2` is the return value of `Increment2` which is a function. Therefore you can call it. So `Increment2` points to a function that takes 0 arguments, however calling it returns a function that takes one argument.

—

For your second question, lambda is an anonymous function. So `(define Func3 (λ(F x)(F x)))` is a variable definition, where you bind the variable `Func3` to an anonymous function, hence, you are naming it and it will act as a regular function.

In fact, you’ve just discovered that the `(define (fun args) ...)` syntax is syntactic sugar for binding a variable to an anonymous function.

—

As for your third question you should be able to answer it if you understand my answer to your first question.